# SQLDeveloper - Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just got started with Oracle, so I don't know anything about it.

I just installed oracle 11g, and used SID: orcl1. After unlocking hr user and giving it a password I downloaded SQLDeveloper and tried to create a connexion with the hr user using SID: orcl1 and it's password.

It gives me the following Error:
SQLDeveloper - Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505. TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

I searched it and seems to be a problem with SID, but I couldn't find a solution and as I'm totally new at this, I don't understand most of the posts. Could anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Pd: I don't know why do I have to make this connection but the instructor of the course I'm following says it's important.

Comment: Is the service name also `orcl1`? Just choosing the other radio button in the SQL Developer connection settings *might* be enough... You can also user `lsnrctl services` to check, or look in the system parameters,

Comment: Thanks for your help but I didn't understand a thing about what you just said. I'm totally new, so could you explain me step by step please?

Comment: When you created the connection in SQL Developer you entered the SID in a text box. To the left of that is a radio button labelled 'SID' which is selected by default. Below those are a second radio choice labelled 'Service name' and a corresponding text box. Click the service name radio button so that is selected, and put `orcl1` in the second text box. Then click 'Test'.

Comment: Another time an Error but this time is: listener refused...ORA-12514. This is giving me so many problems.... is it really that difficult?